# Bool function returns true without meeting condition - ignores printf()

Tags: c, return, boolean, printf, conditional-statements

I've been working 5 days straight on this program, and can't figure out why it's acting like this. Thanks for helping me out.

There is code in the file speller.c that calls 4 functions in the file dictionary.c
In speller.c, it calls a certain function:

```
bool misspelled = !check(word);
```

If misspelled is false, it means the check function returned true.

Here is the check function, in dictionary.c:

```
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int key = hash(word);
    printf("Word: %s    position: %i\n", word, key);
    node* trav = dictArray[key];

    while (trav != NULL)
    {
        if(trav->word == word)
            printf("%s found in the dictionary\n", word);
            return true;
        trav = trav->next;
    }
    printf("%s NOT found in the dictionary\n", word);
    return false;
```

Check() will go check in a hash table if it can find the word passed as argument in a hash table, and prints each word and it's key. If it finds it, it prints a message and return `true`. If not, prints a message saying so, and return `false`.
The hash table is an array of 26 elements, each are a struct with 2 elements, one being a string, the other a pointer to the next struct (node) in the list.
Nodes are added to lists depending on the first letter of the word.

The problem is that I have tested every word that gets added to the array, and even when the word is not there, the function still returns `true`.
In fact, it returns `true` for every word passed as argument.

Now the really puzzling behavior is that check() has to print something to the screen, just before returning either `true` or `false`. Either `...found ...` or `... NOT found ...`.
Well it doesn't. But it still returns 'true', which confuses me.

Any help?
Should I paste the whole code from both file?

Comment: How is there a `bool` in C?

Comment: @Deanie C has has a boolean type since the 1999 standard. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean

Comment: Maybe you mistakenly think `return true;` is part of the `if` condition?

Comment: speller.c calls a header in which <stdbool.h> is #include-d

Comment: Are you trying to compare different strings using `==`? Also, your function always returns true the first time through that while loop. (Modern versions of gcc, at least, will warn you about confusing indentation)

Comment: `if(trav->word == word)` looks suspiciously wrong.  That's not how you compare a string, unless of course you can guarantee that every unique "word" in your system has a unique pointer.

Comment: @M.M What do you mean?

Comment: This is why style guides almost universally insist on all conditional and loop bodies being brace-surrounded blocks. At least while you're learning, it's worth the trouble to obey such a style guide. (And you'll probably grow to like it). Also, *always* ask the compiler to warn you about questionable constructs. Many compilers these days will recognize incorrectly indented code such as yours, and warn you about misleading indentation.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks, figured out that I needed strcpy instead. Appreciate the pointer ;)

Comment: @rici Yeah I think I learned my lesson, will brace-surround everything moving forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look closely:

```
while (trav != NULL)
{
    if(trav->word == word)
        printf("%s found in the dictionary\n", word);
        return true;
    trav = trav->next;
}
```

There are no curly braces around the `if` block.  So with proper indentation what you really have is:

```
while (trav != NULL)
{
    if(trav->word == word)
        printf("%s found in the dictionary\n", word);
    return true;
    trav = trav->next;
}
```

So you always return true on the first loop iteration.

Also, you don't want to use `==` to compare strings.  What you end up doing is comparing the *pointer values*, which will almost always be not equal.  Use `strcmp` to compare strings instead.

The fixed code:

```
while (trav != NULL)
{
    if(!strcmp(trav->word, word)) {
        printf("%s found in the dictionary\n", word);
        return true;
    }
    trav = trav->next;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot to add the curly braces after I added a line for debugging.
Regarding strcmp, I completely forgot about that function and how comparing strings doesn't work with ==.
Cheers

Comment: @PYB That's why you should always use curly braces for inner blocks, even if it's just one line.

Answer (score 1):

This code block:

```
    if(trav->word == word)
        printf("%s found in the dictionary\n", word);
        return true;
```

Doesn't do what you think it does - add `{}` around everything you want to be included in the `if` statement:

```
if(trav->word == word) 
{
    printf("%s found in the dictionary\n", word);
    return true;
}
```

Otherwise that `return true` happens every time (and as you saw, without necessarily printing).